A Question in Fourier Analysis proposing a conjecture
Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodic BV function whose derivative is also BV.Let the amount of jump at a point $x$ is denoted as $\lfloor f \rfloor (x) = f(x+0)-f(x-0)$ Define function $J:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$, such that $J(x) = \lfloor f \rfloor (x)$. Define the set $L = \{x/x\in(0,2\pi)\wedge J(x)\neq 0\}$. Let there not be any jumps at $0, \pi, 2\pi$. and all jumps at rational multiples of $2\pi$.
Let the Fourier series of $f$ be defined as
\begin{equation}
S[f] =  \sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{\nu=\infty}c_{\nu}e^{i\nu x}
%a=x^2
\end{equation}
and the conjugate Fourier series as
\begin{equation}
\tilde{S}[f] =  -i\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{\nu=\infty}sign(\nu)c_{\nu}e^{i\nu x}
\end{equation}
Let the Fourier partial sum of $f$ be defined as
\begin{equation}
S_n(x;f) = \sum_{\nu=-n}^{\nu=n}c_{\nu}e^{i\nu x}
\end{equation}
and the conjugate partial sum of $f$ as
\begin{equation}
\tilde{S}_n(x;f) = -i\sum_{\nu=-n}^{\nu=n}sign(\nu)c_{\nu}e^{i\nu x}
\end{equation}
Define $$G(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|c_i\right|$$
The Dirichlet kernel $D_n(x)$ and conjugate Dirichlet kernel $\tilde{D}_n(x)$ are defined as
\begin{equation}
D_n(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{\nu=1}^{n}\cos(\nu x) = \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tilde{D}_n(x) = \sum_{\nu=1}^{n}\sin(\nu x) = \frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})-\cos(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}
\end{equation}
Let \begin{equation}
    Y_n(x) = -\frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tilde{S}_k(x;f)\left|c_k\right|
    \end{equation}
Conjectures
show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n(x) = \frac{J(x)}{2\pi}
\end{equation}
Given any $(a,b)\subseteq (0,2\pi)$, show that
\begin{equation}
V_a^b(Y_n) \sim \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{x\in L\cap (a,b)}\left|J(x)\right|
\end{equation}
PS: $V_a^b(f)$ is the variation of $f$ in $(a,b)$.

These are proofs for first and second conjectures.
This is a proof to the second conjecture.
Let $$V_n = V_a^b(Y_n)  = \int_a^b\left|\frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tilde{S}'_k(x;f)\left|c_k\right| \right|dx$$
$$V_n \leq \frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}'_k(x;f)\left|c_k\right| \right|dx$$
using a lemma from Trigonometric Series, Volume 1 - Antoni Zygmund
$$V_n \leq \frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')-\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\tilde{D}_k(x-y))\left|c_k\right| \right|dx$$
$$V_n \leq \frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')-\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\tilde{D}_k(x-y))\left|c_k\right| \right|dx$$
$$V_n \leq  \frac{1}{\log(n) G(n)}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')\left|c_k\right|\right|dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\tilde{D}_k(x-y))\left|c_k\right| \right|dx)$$
Since $f'$ is BV, with a suitable reference, $\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')\right|dx \sim O(1)$, So $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')\left|c_k\right|\right|dx \sim \sum_{k=1}^{n}(O(1))\frac{V}{k} \sim O(\log(n))$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\tilde{D}_k(x-y))\left|c_k\right| \right|dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L\setminus(a,b)}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx +  
    \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L\cap(a,b)}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx
$$
$\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx \sim 2\log(k)$ if $y \in (a,b)$ and $\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx \sim O(1)$, if $y \notin (a,b)$
$V_n \leq \frac{1}{\log(n)G(n)}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')\left|c_k\right|\right|dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L\setminus(a,b)}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{y\in L\cap(a,b)}\frac{J(y)}{\pi}\left|c_k\right|\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx$
Therefore
In the first term on the RHS  $\int_a^b\left|\tilde{S}_k(x;f')\right|dx \sim O(1)$ and hence first term goes to zero.
Coming to second term, $y\notin(a,b)$, so  $\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx \sim O(1)$ and hence second term also vanishes.
In the third term $ y \in (a,b)$ and hence $\int_a^b\left|\tilde{D}_k(x-y)\right|dx = 2log(k)$,also $|c_k|\sim \frac{1}{k}$, so after summation via integration and knowing  $G(n)\sim \log(n)$, we get the result, but the equality hold only up to a constant factor.

This is a proof to first conjecture.
Case 1 Points of no jump.
$\tilde{S_n}(x;f)\sim O(1)$ and hence $Y_n(x)\sim 0$, as $J(x) = 0$ for no jump the result is proved.
Case 2 Points of jump.
By Lukacs theorem, at points of jump, $\tilde{S_n}(x;f)\sim \frac{J(x)}{\pi}\log(n)$,
So
$$Y_n(x) = \frac{1}{\log(n)G(n)}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{J(x)}{\pi}\log(k)|c_k|$$
Noting $|c_k|\sim\frac{1}{k}$ (as we are assuming points of jump),
$$Y_n(x) = \frac{1}{\log(n)K\log(n)}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{J(x)}{\pi}\log(k)K^2\frac{1}{k}$$ where $K$ is a constant.
on taking summation as integration, we get $$ \frac{1}{K(\log(n))^2}K\frac{J(x)}{\pi}\int_0^n\log(k)K\frac{1}{k}dk$$
Substituting $\log(k) = t$ in the integral, we get
$$ \frac{1}{(\log(n))^2}\frac{J(x)}{\pi}\int_0^t Ktdt$$
Hence we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n(x) = K \frac{J(x)}{2\pi}$$
equality in conjecture holding only upto a constant factor.
